# Using relationship classes with ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-online, relationship-class, arcgis-collector

I am using ArcInfo 10.4 to create geodatabase with a relationship class associating a point feature to a table with the goal of using it to collect inspection data in the table of the point features through ESRI Collector.  (I am a newbie at ArcGIS but have a lot of Access database experience.)

As I have it set up right now, I can create point feature records in Collector, and can create a new inspection table record from the point feature in Collector, but I can't see why the Global ID (parent key of the GUID field type) from the site feature is not being copied into the rel_Global ID field (foreign key also GUID field type), so the inspections table has the records, but they are not associated with the point feature.

Comment: Global I'd works as expected for attachments only. I use what is not recommended, objectid and field of type long integer in secondary table. Create relationship using arccatalog and make sure that related table present in mxd before sharing this as feature service. Fgdb is a best storage

Answer (score 2):

You have the relationship setup incorrectly. You need to use the GlobalID of the parent and have it go into the GUID field of the child. You cannot write GlobalID to GlobalID b/c the GlobalID is blocked from being edited. When  you create the feature class add an additional GUID field type and use that when setting up the relationship. This will take the GlobalID and populate the GUID, the childs GlobalID field will be used to keep the records unique which is required for offline.

Answer (score 1):

There is a blog post [here](https://geonet.esri.com/people/MKellyesri-ireland-ie-esridist/blog/2016/11/18/related-data-in-arcgis-online) which demonstrates how to create related data in ArcGIS Pro/ArcMap for use in ArcGIS Online/Collector/etc. There are some YouTube videos which guide you through how to set these up which should help! As Russ mentioned, the relationships are more than likely setup incorrectly.